# Some cards in my deck are heads down, can opponent force me to fix that?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I have deck without sleeves, and some cards in my deck are heads down(not upside-down, you don't see the images, but can recognize that some card backs are head down, while others not).

Can my opponent force me to look through my whole deck to fix that?

It happened in my club at least twice. I did not cheat, neither of us who were forced to do that make heads down cards on purpose(we shuffle like that, he insists that those cards may be lands or winconditions), but it eats lots of time to sort them back and is just annoying.

Can I at least force a player that don't like heads down cards(or judge?) to fix that instead of me, if it is in the rules?

Comment: "We shuffle like that" - not sure if you mean you *always* do that or if you just accidentally did it that time, but whatever your shuffling method is, you can presumably do it without turning any cards around. Probably worth paying attention to in the future!

Comment: @Jefromi that's how I do it to shuffle most effectively using least time. When I gather cards after random pile shuffle there are lots of heads down cards.

Comment: Well, might want to practice a different method, then. You do need to be able to randomize your deck and keep all the cards turned the same way. (Also, if by "random pile shuffle" you mean scattering and regathering cards, that's going to be prone to damaging sleeves too, which is another way to end up with illegally marked cards.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Nobody but judges are allowed to look at your deck during the game. You will need a judge to fix your deck.**

During a game, you would obviously not be allowed to look through your deck unless an effect would allow you to.

> 401.2. Each library must be kept in a single face-down pile. Players can’t look at or change the order of cards in a library.

In a tournament setting, your deck would count as marked, and you would get at least a Warning for it, possibly a game loss:

> Tournament Error — Marked Cards
>
> A player’s cards are marked or oriented in a way that could potentially give an advantage to that player.
>
> Penalty - Warning
>
> The Head Judge has the option to upgrade this penalty to a Game Loss if he or she believes that a player noticing the pattern of markings would clearly compromise the integrity of the game.

Only a judge would be allowed to fix your deck as a remedy to the infraction.

If the error was not reported, and the Head Judge is convinced that you knew it was illegal, and that you intended to gain an advantage from the cards' orientation, the infraction would probably be upgraded to Cheating, and you would have to get a disqualification.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's worth noting that in an informal setting, this can be fixed without revealing any of the cards in the library

Comment: In an informal setting people can do whatever, but answering that is not going to be much use to anybody. that's why I chose to answer for the only setting that rules exist for, i.e. a tournament setting

Comment: @Hacksworth You can follow all the comprehensive rules outside of a tournament setting or using any tournament- specific rules.

Comment: Ok so I change my answer to "You can do whatever brah"? or what?

Comment: Not at all, because you still have to follow the rules. The better takeaway would be that upside down cards are illegal; so in a casual setting, it would be handled however your group best deals with an illegal situation.

Comment: Do I get a warning if I use new sleeves that looks the same heads down?

Comment: @desudesudesu Sleeves can't look the same heads down. There's an open side and a closed side. (Unless you're laminating your cards or something?)

Comment: One doesn't have to look at deck to fix it. The problem is with back side. You can fix it while looking only at back side.

Comment: @Gendolkari What specific rule in the Comprehensive Rules says that upside down cards are illegal?

Comment: @Rainbolt It's in the IPG not the CR. Hackworth already quoted the relevant section in his answer.